# Float precision in Python

Tags: python, precision

I have a float,

```
5.8307200000000005e-06
```

But I only want the precision of 5 on it, so it looks like this

```
5.83072e-06
```

How can I do this in Python?

Update, new code

```
def precision(number):
    # The number you want to change the precision of
    number

    # Convert the number to scientific notation
    sci_notation = '{:.5e}'.format(number)

    # Split the scientific notation string into its coefficient and 
exponent parts
    coefficient, exponent = sci_notation.split('e')

    # Round the coefficient to 5 decimal places
    rounded_coefficient = round(float(coefficient), 5)

    # Rebuild the scientific notation string using the rounded 
coefficient and the original exponent
rounded_sci_notation = f'{rounded_coefficient}e{exponent}'

    # Convert the scientific notation string back to a float
    rounded_number = float(rounded_sci_notation)
    return rounded_number
```

Comment: `float` objects have a fixed *precision*. You seem to simply care about how the object is *printed to the screen*, correct?

Comment: No, I need the object in a list, so not only printed. Also, I want a precision of 5 on all my floats, printing "round(5.8307200000000005e-06, 12)" wont work. I tried the Decimal module but was unsuccessful.

Comment: @TullMesh I already explained to you **floats have a fixed precision**. the decimal reprsentation you see printed to the screen is only ever an approximation anyway, floats are binary represenations. Also, "No, I need the object in a list, so not only printed" makes absolutely no sense. What does "I need the object in a list" have to do with "not only printed". Those two things aren't inherently related at all.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't understand what you mean with "floats have a fixed precision", either. Looks like they have the float `5.8307200000000005e-06` and simply want the float `5.83072e-06`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo That other question isn't about *significant* digits. How do you apply that here?

Comment: @KellyBundy would you say the floats `5.83072e-06` and `5.8307200000000000e-06` have the same precision?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't know, depends on what you mean with that.

Comment: @KellyBundy so, the *precision* of a floating point number typically refers to the number of significand bits, which is the same *for all floats*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'd say of *almost* all (since subnormals have less, don't they?). Anyway, apparently the OP means the precision in terms of decimal digits of the default decimal representation. The question seems clear enough to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you format a number with 5 significant digits and scientific notation:

```py
number = 5.8307200000000005e-06
print(f"{number:.5e}")
```

```
>>> 5.83072e-06
```

But this does nothing with the precision of the number, just the way it is printed.....

Comment: use the `decimal` package

Comment: @TullMesh **you cannot change the precision of a `float`, it is a fixed-precision binary floating point format**. This is a very fundamental thing to understand

Comment: @TullMesh and also very crucial to understand, *the decimal representation you see printed doesn't really tell you the precision*. You are talking about "mathematical" precision. In which case, you just need to round.